# can someone help me with 3d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello I'm fairly new to programming. I took an intro to Java class and I'm taking c++.

My question is, in a 3D array:

```
int myArr[a][b][c];
```

which is the one that defines the layers? `a` or `c`?

Comment: What do you mean by "define the layers?"

Comment: Spiral rule: `myArr` is an array of `a` arrays of `b` arrays of `c` `int`s.

Comment: Something you may need to know, but the entire array will be stored sequentially in memory.

Answer (score 4):

The way arrays are allocated in C++, you will have a blocks, each pointing to a b block each pointing to a c block. Like this:

```
 a -> b -> c
           c
           c
      b -> c
           c
           c
```

So, I would say *a* is defining the layers.

Answer (score 3):

`a` would be the variable defining the number of "layers", if you mean each "layer" is a 2d grid of `b` x `c` elements.

Comment: so in an array [2][3][4] the array is of 3x4 and has 2 layers?

Answer (score 1):

When declaring and using a multi-dimensional array, it's up to you to determine which each level of the array means.

```
int myArray[6][3][9]
```

Given this array, just remember that the first index (closest to the variable name) has indicies 0-5, the middle index has indicies 0-2, and the last index has indicies 0-8. As long as you are in bounds for each, you will be fine.

Comment: There is more to it than that. When you're iterating through a large array (of more than one dimension) iterating through the elements in the same order they appear in memory can improve cache usage and therefore give *much* higher performance (I've seen more than 10:1) speed differences.

Comment: so I can make the 9 be my number of layers as well as the 6?

Comment: @Fert09 There's no restriction on indicies other than memory.